# access 2010 One form add information in table1 and table2

Tags: ms-access

I think I have an other quest. I have a form with user information in table one which controls table1. In table2 I have more detailed information. For some reason I get a eeror when I point a text field to [Tabel2]![Bevindingen]

How can I point to table2 field: Bevindingen so when data is entered in that text field is stored in table2?

I think with [Tabel2]![Bevindingen] it's trying to fetch data from that field instead of adding it.

Comment: Templates: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/templates/CT010142616.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your previous question, I think you want a form/subform set up. The form would have the customer details from the customer table (table 1) and the subform would hold data from the problem table (table 2).

It is possible to build a form based on two tables, but it is very rarely a good idea. It is also possible to use Domain Aggregate functions, such as DLookUp to display data from another table, but it is not editable, finally, you can use VBA to fill in controls.